# How to get android menu in a custom button in the same way of action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Due to design needs I cannot use the Action Bar. 
With the old menu button this is not important since all menu commands are displayed in a specific menu, unfortunately some devices as Nexus 4 haven't a menu button and the user cannot access the function of menu.

So I want to include a my personal button that works like the button in the top-right edge of action bar (or physical menu button), getting all commands in OptionsMenu automatically, but I don't know how could I do this without redefine a button for each command separately for menu and for my custom button-menu.

Someone could help me?

Comment: If you are not using action bar, on devices which don't have hardware menu button, there should be displayed another display, on the black system bar at bottom of screen, where home,back button are placed. For  example Facebook app is behaving this way.

Comment: So you want an Action Bar with a menu button but cannot use the Action Bar?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I have said "Design needs" for a reason

Comment: @Android-Developer But not in full-screen mode

Comment: You mean in fullscreen mode the button is not showing?

Comment: @Android-Developer Maybe I haven't understood, I'm trying the app on Nexus 4 emulator and I cannot see any menu button, only back-home-swith task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, first of all I know that you should go with your design stuff, but it's really a better option to use `ActionBar` or `ActionBarSherlock` for new applications. But in order to give the right answer to your question, you should do a few things before showing software menu button in bottom system bar next to home and back button.

First of all include your menu as always :

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

And second thing which you should change is in your `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Take a look at this line :

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
```

this is the place where magic happens. If you set your `targetSdkVersion` bigger than 10, it means that your app supports devices with no hardware menu button and probably use `ActionBar` or some other way.

If you do everything as above you will get on Nexus4/Nexus7 screen like this :

[image]

Hope this helps!

**P.S**. And just to say again, building application you should consider using the latest available design guidelines and best practices in coding.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. No way to view the 4th button menu like in the screenshot If targetSdk is > 10?

Comment: If the device has no hardware menu button, you won't see it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want a `Button` that opens up your `menu.xml` or whatever you may be calling it. If so, you can use [PopupMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html). Note that this requires `API >= 11`. I had to create my own "ActionBar" to get the look and functionality that I needed and `PopupMenu` has worked out nicely. This allows you to inflate `R.menu.your_menu` and has `interfaces` and methods that allow you to use it as a `menu`.

I put my functionality into a `BaseActivity` which is a super class for all of my other `Activities` then I can `override` `onMenuItemClick` if I need different functionality in certain `Activities`.

Let me know if I misunderstand what you need.

Comment: I need simply to emulate the behavior of physical menu button when click on my custom ImageButton