# How to center image in android action bar, with action items on each side

Tags: java, android, xml, android-actionbar

Yes this question has been asked before. Two times actually,

[ActionBar - custom view with centered ImageView, Action Items on sides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026818/actionbar-custom-view-with-centered-imageview-action-items-on-sides)

[ActionBar logo centered and Action items on sides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750013/actionbar-logo-centered-and-action-items-on-sides)

Yes I have thoroughly read both and it works except, I cant figure out how to put items to the LEFT of the image. To quote from the second link:

> Of course, make sure you also do the other necessary setups for the
>   Action items in your menu xml's as well. This will be for any
>   right-sided action items.

Not much help. This doesn't apply to placement:

```
To take control of the left action item, you could do this in your Activity:

@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.yourRightActionItem:
                        //do something
                        return true;
        case android.R.id.home: //<-- this will be your left action item
            // do something
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

I have tried many things, but never can get buttons to the left. Can someone clear this up for me?

Comment: From what I have seen, the `ActionBar` doesn't seem to leave a lot of room for customization (at least not how I needed). So I created my own layout to use for it and implement it in a `BaseActivity` and that has worked out well for me. [This answer discusses it a little](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432603/how-to-get-android-menu-in-a-custom-button-in-the-same-way-of-action-bar/17433066#17433066)

Comment: Be advised that what you seek goes against the Android design guidelines.

Comment: @CommonsWare so how would you do it?

Comment: Have the logo on the left.

Comment: haha, client doesnt want that, @CommonsWare

Comment: What your client wants goes against the Android design guidelines.

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you link said guideline?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html Also http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pEGWcMTxs3I, as this is one of the 10 UI anti-patterns cited in the video.